# Grouping cells with formulas [in EXCEL]

Tags: microsoft-excel

If I have two cells,

A1 has the world Hello, A2 has the word World.

So if I type into another cell, =A1&A2 I will get HelloWorld

I would really like to know what day it is too,

So I tried to type in =A1&A2&NOW() but the output is, HelloWorld44728.5556479167

I have also tried, =CONCATENATE without success.

Answer (score 0):

Use TEXT function to format the date and time to your desired formula. Your formula should look like the following.

```
=A1 & A2 & TEXT(NOW(),"dd/MM/yyyy")
```

Adapt the format.

Answer (score 0):

Good Day,

Adding TEXT(Today(),"MMMM DD") to your formula will probably help. See an example below.

[image]

Hopefully, this helps

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula:

```
=A1&A2&TEXT(NOW(),"yyyy/m/d h:mm")
```

[image]